# MEMORY UNMAPPING

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, driver

I want to unmap the memory mapped by my custom character driver, through an ioctl call. is there any kernel API for that??

From userspace app1, I will be accessing my bar memory in a loop. Through an ioctl call from another user app2, i need to remove the mapping so that access my aap1 will create an SIGBUS error.

io_remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, paddr >> PAGE_SHIFT, size, vma->vm_page_prot);

Comment: A process(application) cannot map and unmap memory for **other processes**.

Comment: Is it possible to restrict the access to the particular physical range,  so that any memory access to this will cause an an error in user space. I will be restricting(from driver) the access in the middle of memory access by user application.

Comment: "Is it possible to restrict the access to the particular physical range" - No, this is not possible too. (Well, in the kernel space your could do technically anything. But doing things which are not designed by the Linux kernel would require quite a lot of efforts).

Comment: Please include the code that does the mapping.

Comment: after mapping even if i delete the driver node the user space application is able to access the memory that is mapped earlier.